# Excel runs very slow (with VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with several drop-down lists, which are populated via a VBA macro. This happens right at the beginning, on opening the workbook.

Once the load is done, the workbook becomes very slow. Even scrolling from one cell to another causes very noticeable lag, despite not having any running macro.

On opening the workbook, a Load() function is called which essentially preps the userform.

The userform has ~25 dropdown lists, which are populated from a separate sheet ("Menu") which stores the values for each of these dropdowns in a separate column. The "Menu" sheet is filled up via the Load() function which calls one of two MenuQuery() routines.

One of these pick up distinct values from certain columns in a dbf file, the other lists down the options based on the list in question.

Snippets from the Load() subroutine :

```
Sub Load()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


Dim MySht, Datasht As Worksheet



Set MySht = Sheets("Dashboard")
Set Datasht = Sheets("Menu")


MySht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
MySht.Activate

Datasht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Datasht.Activate


ActiveSheet.Range("A1:IV2000").Select
Selection.ClearContents


Range("A1").Select
Call MenuQuery("A", "Type", "hh", "CmbBox1")
Call MenuQuery1("B", "Flow", "flow", "CmbBox2")  

.
'25 similar calls
.

Datasht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden 
    .
.'Hide some sheets
.
Sheets("Triggers").Visible = xlVeryHidden
Sheets("Actions").Visible = xlVeryHidden


MySht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
MySht.Activate


End Sub
```

What I've tried:

1. Have tried commenting out the MenuQuery() functions and the problem persists. So I guess that isnt the problem here
2. Tried with Application.ScreenUpdating=False in the beginning of the function, no change
3. In fact, I just tried not calling the Load() function, but that doesn't seem to help either!

Comment: We might need a bit more information to help, and some indication of what you've tried so far.

Comment: Did you define any event handlers? Do you use recursive calls to populate your list?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking here. As you haven't provided details of your Macro it's impossible to determine whether or not the VBA code is the source of your lag issue. As it stands the question isn't about programming and doesn't really belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: Now you've posted up some more details, I've voted to reopen.

Comment: It should be Application.ScreenUpdating = False at the beginning of the code AND Application.ScreenUpdating = True at the end, not only at the beginning... Do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel VBA macro code that runs slow, the chances are it's caused by Excel having to recalculate at each line of code. Deleting rows is one of many things that can become painfully slow. This can be overcome very easily by switching Excel into manual calculation before your code runs. Just be aware that if your code bugs out, and you have no error trap, the Workbook will be left in manual calculation and NO properly designed spreadsheet should ever be used with calculation in manual.
 If you ever get advice to switch Excel into manual calculation to prevent slow saving, closing and data entry...run very fast! 
This is a band aid approach rather than addressing the underlying cause.
If you run any Excel Workbook in manual calculation it's only a matter of time before non-calculated data is read off!